# CoreBluetooth: Turn Bluetooth on/off with button press

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

Is there any way to turn bluetooth on off without going in the settings???

Something like this:

```
[centralManager setBluetoothAktiv:true];
```

Best Regards

Comment: No the iOS SDK does not allow this.

Comment: ty for your fast response